# Images three times their normal height on mobile device

Tags: html, css, image

I'm developping a website and I encoutered a problem that shows only on a few pages of my website. The problem appears on this page : https://clad.web.epfprojets-sceaux.com/clad.php.

On my laptop, `height : auto;` works well. When I simulate an iPhone 8 in my laptop, images are still showing fine. But when I look at the website on my actual iPhone 8, the two first images in black and white are three times their normal height : [Images too tall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iMtw.png)

It's also the case for the image making the transition between the orange and the "white" at the bottom of the page.

I also have this problem at https://clad.web.epfprojets-sceaux.com/x_details_produits?id=1 with the two last images showing the product. The first one displays fine.

Anyone understands the problem?

Comment: Can't reproduce with Chrome Dev Tools mobile view.

Comment: Yes the problem doesn't with Crome Dev Tools but appears in my cell phone

Comment: Any chance you could post your code as a runnable snippet for others to test/troubleshoot?

Comment: I am new to Stack Overflow, can you explain how do I do that?

Comment: I do see the problem on IOS14 on an iPad and in both landscape and portrait orientation. It's almost as if the system is using the intrinsic height of the image rather than its height scaled down.

Comment: I use this in my head `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">` Could it be related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution.

The images appearing too tall still had the correct width. From the image ratio, I calculated the height I wanted in javascript and applied it to the image, just like this :

```
width_image_1 = $('#img_section_photo_1').width();
$('#img_section_photo_1').css("height", width_image_1 * 1.32423924449);
```